# React-Native accessing the component's attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a project in React-Native. I have a button component in my project and I want to access the title property of this component. I googled this but couldn't find it, can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean props?

Comment: yes for example <Button title="Home" ..../> I want to access the title's here (I'm sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://reactnative.dev/docs/tutorial#props

Comment: yes, but there is no similarity between this topic and what I want, but it seems like I found a way myself

Comment: whatway did you find?

Comment: OMG!! I struggled with this all day but the method I tried didn't work. I'm about to go crazy.